# Php Convert PNG to SVG with ImageMagick

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick

I want to convert PNG files to SVG format with PHP and ImageMagick.

My PNG files background are transparent and colors are black. So there is an color shape (black). 
I used this code "convert a.png b.svg" on terminal but, converted file's size very big. (9 MB ~). My png's size is only 16 KB.

How Can I convert PNG to SVG with other method ?

*[NOTE !]: I don't want to convert SVG to PNG !!!*

Ex. My PNG file: 
[image]

Comment: Oops, sorry about that!

Comment: I suggest you try using a tool like [AutoTrace](http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/) or [Delineate](http://delineate.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I solved this problem ;) I used convert + potrace ;)

Comment: @s3yfullah  I am stuck with same issue.  can you please share your code snippet.

Comment: @AbhinavKulshreshtha For this conversion you need to install ImageMagick and potrace. potrace can convert pbm/pgm/ppm/bmp to svg. So at first we need to convert png/jpg to pbm/pgm/ppm/bmp using imagemagick. Than we will convert it to svg using potrace via command line. https://github.com/IJmouri/raster-_images-png-jpg-_to_svg